# Returning value in conditional operator

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator

I was trying to return value true or false depending upon the condition by using a conditional operator but I got an error. Here is my code,

```
bool isEmpty()
{
    int listSize = Node::size();
    listSize > 0 ? return (true) : return (false);
    return false;
}
```

And here is the error,

```
error C2107: illegal index, indirection not allowed
```

Now I am stuck here. I don't get the point.Logically I think it should be correct. Please guide me about it . Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only have expressions* as the operands of the ternary conditional, not statements. The usual way to say this is:

```
return listSize > 0 ? true : false;
```

or even better,

```
return listSize > 0;
```

or even better,

```
bool isEmpty() { return Node::size() > 0; }
```

*) Since you tagged this as both C and C++, know that there is a [subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c) between the admissible expressions in the two languages.

Comment: Thanks that you mentioned the difference. As it was just a snippet I thought it would be better to tag both languages.

Comment: The last one may look good. But when you enter debug time you will wish you had assigned the result to a temporary before returning so that it is east to inspect.

Comment: @Kerrek By any chance, do we need to put the ternary condition inside braces? I got a code review comment to do that.

Comment: @cppcoder: You don't need to. But depending on how you use it, it might help the reader. Do *you* know what `a ? b : c = d` does? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek What will be the precedence here? I guess, it will assign `d` to `c` and return `c` if `a<=0`

Comment: @cppcoder: That's the point: If you have to guess, you should add parentheses :-) (And it's quite an interesting point what this expression really does.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Please reply what is the exact behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The ternary operator (`?:`) is not designed to be used like that.  You have a syntax error.

Try this instead:

```
return (listSize > 0);
```

Comment: Nice, simple and short. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a deeper reason for doing this that I am missing, you should just `return (listSize > 0);`.

Comment: Nice, simple and short. Thanks :)