# Lvalue required error in C

Tags: c++, c, variables, conditional-operator, lvalue

my code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   int a=10, b;
   a >= 5 ? b=100 : b=200;
   printf("%d %d", a, b);
   return 0;
}
```

Here comes a "Lvalue Required" in the line of conditional operator.

Can you explain me why?

By the way, the same program is perfectly working in C++.

Comment: Try adding parentheses. `=` has pretty low priority.

Comment: yes. it is working out with parentheses... but the older one is still working in C++. i just wanted to know the reason that why there is an error in C then?

Comment: Because c is not c++?

Comment: @Tim :) :) This is not good reason, You may like [Charles Bailey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c/1082680#1082680) for technical reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write that assignment is:

```
b = (a >= 5) ? 100 : 200;
```

If you insist on keeping it your way, add parentheses:

```
(a >= 5) ? (b=100) : (b=200);
```

For details on why this works in C++ but not in C, see [Conditional operator differences between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c) (thanks @Grijesh Chauhan!)

Comment: yes. it is working out with parentheses... but the older one is still working in C++. so why there is an error in C then?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal [**Conditional operator differences between C and C++**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c)

Answer (score 1):

parenthesis have the higher precedence in C.. U get the warning due to precedence problem..
Try this..

```
(a >= 5) ? (b = 100) : (b = 200);
```