# llvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I wan't to open a file in append mode or erase all it's contents based on $flag

```
static void do_redirect(int filedes, const char *filename, int flag){
int rc;
int fd;

flag == 1 ? fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0644) : 
            fd = open(filename, O_CREAT| O_RDWR, 0644);

}
```

Why do I get llvalue required as left operand of assignment?

Comment: In this case, `if..else` would be much clearer than `?:`, and prevent this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of precedence. The expression is parenthesised implicitly

```
(flag == 1 ? fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0644) : fd) = open(filename, O_CREAT| O_RDWR, 0644);
```

and the value of the conditional expression is not an lvalue.

Write

```
flag == 1 ? (fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0644)) : 
            (fd = open(filename, O_CREAT| O_RDWR, 0644));
```

or move the conditional expression inside the `open` call.

Comment: also shouldn't fd be FILE* ?

Comment: @BarathBushan Shouldn't you be reading the documentation of `open()` and/or `FILE *`?

Comment: @BarathBushan In short, you mistook `open` for `fopen`. `fopen` returns a `FILE*`, and `open` a file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of precedence.

I would suggest you rewrite it as such:

```
fd = open(filename, O_CREATE | O_RDWR | (flag == 1 ? O_TRUNC : 0), 0644);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Why you are getting lvalue error?**

You conditional expression is something like:

```
flag == 1 ? fp = 1 : fp = 2;
```

that is parsed in C like:

```
(flag == 1 ? fp = 1 : fp) = 2;  

  ^ expression            = value
```

and you can't assign a value to an expression that  that reason for lvalue error.

The correct answer is given by @Daniel Fischer by adding parenthesis you can rectify your conditional expression(*actually overriding precedence*).

But interesting this you expression is correct in C++ language!
Read Charles Bailey's  answer here: [*Conditional operator differences between C and C++*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c). You will also find an elaborate answer there why you are getting lvalue error.
(*my answer is just a reference to there*)

Although @Daniel Fischer and @Joachim Pileborg answer you two tricks you can also achieve same like this:

```
fd = flag == 1 ? -2 : 3 ;
```

<sub>Yes but this is possible only in your case because you are using `fd` in both true/false expression</sub>