# Array initialization with a ternary operator?

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I don't have access to the C11 specification, therefore I can't investigate this bug.

The following declaration rises an error during compilation:

```
int why[2] =  1 == 1 ? {1,2} : {3,4};
```

The error is: expected expression before { and: expected expression before :

Comment: Have you tried this: int why[2] =  (1 == 1) ? {1,2} : {3,4};

Comment: yes: this makes no difference

Comment: It does not exist in syntax of the array initialization .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not valid C11.

You can only initialize an array with an initializer-list not with an expression.

```
int why[2] = { ... };  // initializer-list {}
```

Moreover, `1 == 1 ? {1,2} : {3,4}` is not a valid C expression because `{1, 2}` is not a C expression.

Just for information using compound literals you can have something close to what you want using a pointer object:

```
int *why = (1 == 1) ? (int[2]) {1,2} : (int[2]) {3,4};
```

Comment: @RudiRüssel yes, that one is valid but there is no `{1, 2}` expression here and `works` is not an array.

Comment: @RudiRüssel: Expressions are things with values. `6 * 7` has a value. Initializer lists are not expressions; they are just a syntax for describing multiple values to be put into at object when it is initialized. The source code `{1, 2}` is not a value or an object or anything you can manipulate. It is just a description of what to put into an array. Because it is not an expression, you cannot operate on it; you cannot use it as an operand in for `? :` or for other operators.

Comment: +love your solution very nice I means `int *why = (1 == 1) ? (int[2]) {1,2} : (int[2]) {3,4};`

Comment: @Eric Thank you!  In the C EBNF a **block** is a __statement__ but not an __[conditional-]expression__

Comment: @CustomCalc Incorrect comment coming from an incorrect assumption. In a function a compound literal has automatic storage duration and its lifetime ends on exit from the block where it appears. Outside the body of a function it has static storage duration and its lifetime is the entire execution of the program.

Comment: @ouah, wow mind blown. So if I take this into C++ I get a dangerous address to a temporary, but in C99 and up it's basically an unnamed object in the current scope. Thank you.

Comment: @ouah, what is the existing duration of (int[2]) {1,2} may I ask? will it be reclaimed outside the scope? –

Answer (score 2):

from Charles Bailey's answer here: [Gramma from  conditional-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c)

```
   conditional-expression:
        logical-OR-expression
        logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

And

```
  1 == 1 ? {1,2} : {3,4}; 
           ^        ^       are not expressions
```

that is the reason compiler gives error like:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token    // means after ?
error: expected expression before ‘:’ token    // before :
```

**Edit** as @Rudi Rüssel commented:

following is a valid code in c:

```
int main(){
    {}
    ;
    {1,2;}
}
```

we use `{}` to combine statements `;` in C.

**note:** if I write `{1,2}` then its error `(*expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token*)`, because `1,2` is an expression but *not* a statement.

For OP: what is [The Expression Statement in C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t054cy7(v=vs.80).aspx) and what is [Block Statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc08csor.htm) and [Expression Statements](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc08csor.htm)

edit2:
Note: How @ouah uses typecase to convert it into expression, yes:

To understand run this code:

```
int main(){
 printf("\n Frist = %d, Second =  %d\n",((int[2]){1,2})[0],((int[2]) {1,2})[1]);
}
```

It works like:

```
~$ ./a.out 

 Frist = 1, Second =  2
```

Comment: For my understanding: what is `{1,2}` if not an expression?

Comment: @RudiRüssel: `{1, 2}` is an initializer. This is described in clause 6.7 of the 2011 C standard. Expressions are described in a different clause, 6.5.

Comment: @Grijesh Thank you for your answer, but ouah also added a workaround with compound literals.

Comment: @RudiRüssel Yes and very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initializer lists are not expressions, so they cannot be used in expressions.

I suggest you leave the array uninitialized and use memcpy.

```
int why[2];
memcpy( why, 1 == 1 ? (int[2]){1,2} : (int[2]){3,4}, sizeof why );
```