# Lvalue required Error

Tags: c, ternary-operator, lvalue

visual studio does not report any error for this program while turbo c/c++ says 'Lvalue required in function main'

```
int main()
{
  int a=10,b; 
  a>=5?b=100:b=200;
  printf("%d",b);
  return 0;

}
```

to avoid error : a>=5 ? b=100 :(b=200);

why is it so ? explain.

Comment: There's an answer with a good explanation, but for the sake of readability, I'd recommend you change it to `b = (a>=5?100:200);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, the ternary conditional operator takes an *assignment-expression* as it's third operand, so your expression is understood as:

```
(a >= 5 ? b = 100 : b) = 200;
```

In the "true" case this amounts to:

```
b = 100 = 200;
```

This in turn groups right-to-left, i.e.:

```
b = (100 = 200);
```

This clearly doesn't make sense.

---

What you meant to say is:

```
if (a >= 5) { b = 100; } else { b = 200; }
```

You don't need an expression; a statement is perfectly fine. Alternatively, as Michelle suggests:

```
int b = a >= 5 ? 100 : 200;
```

---

Note that the ternary conditional operator is *different* in C, although it looks similar!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: That depends what you expect of your compiler. Visual Studio speaks its own dialect that isn't really proper C++...

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard C syntax this ternary expression must be parsed as if it was:

```
 (a>=5?b=100:b)=200
```

The workaround is adding parentheses, like you have done, or using an if-statement, or writing the expression as

```
b = a>=5? 100: 200;
```

The C++ language has slightly different syntax rules that make the expression parse the way you expect. It sounds like turbo c/c++ is following C rules white visual studio is applying C++ rules. See also: [Conditional operator differences between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c)

Answer (score 1):

On line 4 your code `a>=5?b=100:b=200;` is half an *expression*.

The C tenernary operator `?:` yields an *lvalue* expression i.e. an expression with a result.
It can be thought of as analogous to a function return, but the value is not silently discarded in this case.

think of the `?:` operator as `result = if(test evaluates to true)then this else that` where `then` is the `?` and `else` is the `:`

You should therefore rewrite the line as `b = (a>=5)?100:200;`
or

```
if (a >=5)     //test
{              //'?'
    b = 100;  
}
else
{          //':'
    b = 200
}
```