# Why can a braced-init-list not be used as an expression in a conditional operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, initialization, conditional-operator

My compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 RC.

```
int f(bool b)
{
    return {}; // OK
    return b ?  1  : { }; // C2059: syntax error : '{'
    return b ?  1  : {0}; // C2059: syntax error : '{'
    return b ? {1} : {0}; // C2059: syntax error : '{'
}
```

Why can braced-init-list not be used in ternary operator?

**Is this behavior defined as ill-formed by the C++ standard, or just a bug of the VC++ compiler?**

Comment: `{}` is not an expression, check grammar here [Conditional operator differences between `C` and `C++`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1082680/1673391)

Comment: Syntax error is due to `?:` operator but not because of  `return`, so consider grammar of Conditional operator. And An expression is "a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation" (that's the definition given in the C++ standard)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, here's what a note in the [C++11 standard, [dcl.init.list] p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list#1) says:

> List-initialization can be used
>
> - as the initializer in a variable definition ([dcl.init])
> - as the initializer in a new expression ([expr.new])
> - in a return statement ([stmt.return])
> - as a function argument ([expr.call])
> - as a subscript ([expr.sub])
> - as an argument to a constructor invocation ([dcl.init], [expr.type.conv])
> - as an initializer for a non-static data member ([class.mem])
> - in a *mem-initializer* ([class.base.init])
> - on the right-hand side of an assignment ([expr.ass])

Since this doesn't mention the conditional operator, your compiler is right. Also note that the conditional operator expects expressions on the both sides of `:` ([[expr.cond]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.cond)), and a *braced-init-list* is not an expression.

Answer (score 8):

It's a syntax error.  A braced-init-list is not an expression, and it doesn't have a type or value category.  braced-init-list is available at various locations in the C++ grammar, and the operands of conditional expression are not one of those locations.  Therefore your code fails to even parse.

If you want to do this:

```
struct T { ... };

T f(bool b)
{
    return b ? {i,j,k} : {x,y};
}
```

instead you could do this:

```
T f(bool b)
{
    return b ? T{i,j,k} : T{x,y};
}
```

and I believe, although this requires a move constructor, it wouldn't use it and RVO would kick in.

Alternatively you could of course do this:

```
T f(bool b)
{
    if (b)
        return {i,j,k};
    else
        return {x,y};
}
```

to get all the advantages of list-initialization.