# Why lvalue is required in shorthand if-else in the else part when using a assignment operator?

Tags: c, shorthand-if

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int k = 8;
        int m = 7;
        int z = k < m ? k = m : m++;
        printf("%d", z);

        k = 8;
        m = 7;
        z = k < m ? m++ : k=m;
        printf("%d", z);
    }
```

Output

```
Compile Error:
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:19:32: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
         z = k < m ? m++ : k=m;
                            ^
```

- Why the first assignment works and second doesn't?
- And why the compiler tells that lvalue is required?

Comment: Perhaps you should have asked "what is lvalue" first!!

Comment: why ask? just google it...

Comment: Stackoverflow was not allowing me post the question, it said my question is mostly code, so i wrote that question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of `?:` conditional operator in comparison to `=`

```
z = k < m ? m++ : k=m;
```

Is equivalent to (or say parse as):

```
z = ((k < m ? m++ : k) = m);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
//    expression       = m
```

`m` is assigned to an expression that is - [Lvalue](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Flvalue.htm) error.

Read [Conditional operator differences between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c)