# How does C infer "assignable values" / l-values

Tags: c, dereference, lvalue

This just puzzled me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int a = 0, b = 1;
  int *ptr = argc <= 1 ? &a : &b;
  (*ptr)++; //does work, of course

  (*(argc <= 1 ? &a : &b))++; //inlining, does also work

  int *ptr_a = &a;
  int *ptr_b = &b;

  (*(argc <= 1 ? ptr_a : ptr_b))++; //variables carry "assignability"

  (argc <= 1 ? *ptr_a : *ptr_b)++; //if-expression does not carry "assignability"?

  return 0;
}
```

I always assumed that "assignability" is a type-property. Hence I thought the last statement should work just fine, instead it is rejected. So why does the dereference have to be the outermost operator for a C-compiler to figure out that the lhs is actually a memory location?

edit: I doubt it has something to do with OS/compiler but the C standard, but here is my compiler setup:

```
clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

And here is the error:

```
test.c:15:32: error: expression is not assignable
  (argc <= 1 ? *ptr_a : *ptr_b)++; //if-expression does not carry "assignability"?
```

edit2: What interests me most is, why C seems to carry the "assignability" property through some but not all expressions.

Comment: Well...assuming addition of pointers would make sense: One can assign something to `*(ptr_a+ptr_b)` but not to  `*ptr_a + *ptr_b`. It´s nothing else here. These two expressions aren´t the same (first add address, second add values) too, aside from syntax

Comment: this is not a problem of using *ptr_a + *ptr_b you are adding two values e.g a and b.

Comment: What is the error. Is it L value required. Please share your aerror.

Comment: @asifaftab87: Yes, i know that

Comment: I know we can't use conditional statement inside ternary operator but what is the problem here I am not getting. Mention your error, OS and compiler. This information will help me to try to solve your issue.

Comment: @asifaftab87: OS and compiler is irrelevant.

Comment: note: you have c++ comments in C code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the conditional operator in C promotes the 2nd and 3rd operands to match each other. A promoted variable is a rvalue and not a lvalue, so the **?: always returns a rvalue**.

The * operator on the other hand, returns a lvalue. That is why `(*(argc <= 1 ? ptr_a : ptr_b))++` works, because ++ is applied to the result of * which is a lvalue.

But in the case of `(argc <= 1 ? *ptr_a : *ptr_b)` the result is a rvalue so ++ cannot be used.

([Please note that C and C++ are different in this case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c))

Comment: `ptr_a` and `ptr_b` both have the same type though, so no promotion would occur.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the derefernce `*` operator returns a l-value **when applied to a pointer**.
In case of

```
(*(argc <= 1 ? &a : &b))++;
```

Either `&a` or `&b` is returned (a r-value but, a **pointer** will be returned). After that the **derefernce is applied on either of two pointer and this will return a l-value**. Increment operator can applied to it as its need a l-value as its operand.
You can also understand this as; if `argc = 1`, then the expression would be like

```
*(&a);
```

`&a` returns the address of `a` and deferencing it will return a l-value.

In case of

```
(argc <= 1 ? *ptr_a : *ptr_b)++;
```

`*ptr_a` or `*ptr_b` is returned (in this case a r-value is returned). As the operand of increment operator `++` must be a l-value, the above statement will produce error.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation. In the very first sentence you wrote it returns an l-value. and the dereference is evaluated first , just as in the second example, isn't it? so what's the difference?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; OK. Let me explain it a bit more.

Comment: I think the real explanation lies in the details of how the ternary operator works.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; No. I explained it in more detailed.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your answer. In the first sentence you say (correctly) that * yields an l-value. In your last sentence you say (correctly) that * is evaluated before ++. And your conclusion is that this yields an r-value? So the order of evaluations effects the result-type of pointer dereference?

Comment: @choeger; In fact this is a little bit tricky. I edited the answer. Read it again.

Comment: So what is a "raw value" and why is it returned here?

Comment: OK. First answer me: Is this correct `int i = 0; (++i)++;` ?

Comment: *(&a) is equal a, * value at, & address at, so writing *(&a) is same as writing a and this must not returns L value error.

Comment: @asifaftab87; Then what?

Comment: It just simply returning the value stored in that location, if int a=10 and int *p=&a then *p=10, *(&a)=a=10. you can check.

Comment: @haccks: sry, I downvoted, there's no such thing as "raw value", I've found your explanation very confusing. after some googling.. see my answer.

Comment: Indeed this has nothing to do with order of evaluation etc and everything to do with the obscure promotion rules of the ?: operator.

Comment: @Lundin; Where did I said that this has something to do with order of evaluation?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; I do not see how it is differ from while I tried to explain it. I am really disappointed by downvoes to this answer :(

Comment: @haccks: oh come on... I said it's because of the ternary operator you said **no**. "*ptr_b is evaluated before the increment applied to it and hence returns r-value" - this is just plain wrong. as I said, it's because of the ternary operator. and Lundin was right, you were referring to evaluation order, which is, again, wrong.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; No. `"*ptr_b is evaluated before the increment applied to it and hence returns r-value" ` is meant for the same that `?:` returns a r-value although its wording might be wrong and confusing. I just tried to explain this to OP. Regarding of your question that "the real explanation lies in the details of how the ternary operator works": I said no because I was fully concentrated at that time on the **operand of `++`** , which must be a l-value.

Comment: @haccks: so you see there's nothing wrong with the downvotes. don't worry, we *all* make mistakes. after all, we are humans ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; Yes :). But my intention was to give a clear explanation but I failed to do so, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the ternary operator *always returns an r-value* - [Conditional operator differences between C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c)

In the second example, you directly apply post-increment to it, but that operator expects an l-value, so it's not a valid code.

In the first example, you do pointer dereferencing, which *turns it to an l-value*, hence the code is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose

```
  int a = 0, b = 1;
  int *ptr_a = &a;
  int *ptr_b = &b;
```

we can increase the value of variable means having some location. 
If you try to modify a constant then you get error L value required means Location required and constants do not have any location and hence the error.

Comment: you explanation is wrong. `(*ptr_a)++` is valid code. in fact, it's used quite heavily.