# Why and when does the ternary operator return an lvalue?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, rvalue, lvalue

For a long time I thought that the ternary operator always returns an rvalue. But to my surprise it doesn't. In the following code I don't see the difference between the return value of `foo` and the return value of the ternary operator.

```
#include <iostream>
int g = 20 ;

int foo()
{
    return g ;
}

int main()
{
    int i= 2,j =10 ;

    foo()=10 ; // not Ok 
    ((i < 3) ? i : j) = 7; //Ok
    std::cout << i <<","<<j << "," <<g << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: Ona side note, if you change `int foo()` to `int &foo()`, then the `foo()=10;` also works.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c. As noted there, you could always do `*((i<3) ? &i : &j) = 7;` so the C++ rule could be summarized as "that still works, even without `*&`"

Comment: In C, the conditional operator never yields an lvalue. In C++, it sometimes does. This is one example of why people should refrain from referring to "C/C++". There are all sorts of subtle differences like this that *may* end up being relevant to any particular question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Both `i` and `j` are *glvalues* (see [this value category reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) for details).

Then if you read [this conditional operator reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) we come to this point:

> 4) If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value category, then the result has the same type and value category

So the result of `(i < 3) ? i : j` is a glvalue, which can be assigned to.

However doing something like that is really not something I would recommend.

Comment: I'm wondering about the meaning of lvalue!! can we always put an lvalue at the left hand side of an assignment operator?

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar Yes, that's where the "l" in "lvalue" comes from, from being on the *left* hand side of an assignment. Another common test is if the address of the value could be taken (using the address-of operator `&`), but that's not always true IIRC (don't remember the details though).

Comment: @Siome programmer dude From cppreference a string literal, such as "Hello, world!" is an lvalue!! How can we put a string literal as a left hand side of an assignment

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar That's because it's not a *modifiable* lvalue. You can take the address of a literal string (using the address-of operator `&`) though. Reading through the "lvalue properties" list on cppreference, all lvalues can have its address taken, but not all can be assigned to. So I was wrong in my first comment (had it the opposite).

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar The problem there is constness, not value category. You can't put an object with a deleted `operator=` on the left side of an assignment; that doesn't make it not an lvalue.

Comment: If we try to write something stupid like `` "Hello" = "World" `` the compiler will give us a misleading error message like error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Your first comment represents the origin of the concept of lvalues: Something that can be on the left hand side of an assignment. While the concept has moved beyond that, the name remains.

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar arrays (such as string literals for example) are tricky lvalues. When their value is used, they implicitly convert to a pointer to first element (this is called decaying) and the decayed pointer is *not* an lvalue. That's the reason for the error diagnostic. More generally though, arrays are simply not assignable in the language even if they aren't const.

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar - Which compiler? gnu c++'s diagnostic for `"Hello" = "World"` is `error: assignment of read-only location '"Hello"'`, while LLVM's is `error: read-only variable is not assignable`.

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar Literal strings are arrays of `const char`. They decay to *constant* pointers to the first element of the array (constant pointer because the location of a literal string can't be changed either). This pointer is of type `const char * const`. Since the pointer is constant you can't change it, which means it's not possible to put it on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @DavidHammen GCC 4.9.2,

Comment: The main use case for this is initialization of references: `int &i = b ? i1 : i2;`

Answer (score 22):

The rules for this are detailed in [[expr.cond]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cond). There are many branches for several combinations of types and value categories. But ultimately, the expression is a prvalue in the default case. The case in your example is covered by paragraph 5:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value
>   category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value
>   category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a
>   bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

Both `i` and `j`, being variables names, are lvalue expressions of type `int`. So the conditional operator produces an `int` lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Ternary conditional operator will yield an lvalue, if the type of its second and third operands is an lvalue.

You can use the function template `is_lvalue` (below) to find out if an operand is an lvalue and use it in the function template `isTernaryAssignable` to find out if it can be assigned to.

A minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_lvalue(T&&) {
  return std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{};
}

template <typename T, typename U>
bool isTernaryAssignable(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return is_lvalue(std::forward<T>(t)) && is_lvalue(std::forward<U>(u));
}

int main(){
    int i= 2,j =10 ;

    ((i < 3) ? i : j) = 7; //Ok

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isTernaryAssignable(i, j); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isTernaryAssignable(i, 10); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isTernaryAssignable(2, j); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isTernaryAssignable(2, 10); std::cout << '\n';   
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
false
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nfidb12MPyvyXLW3)

**Note**: The operands you pass to `isTernaryAssignable` are to be such that they will not undergo decay (For example an array which decays to pointer).

Comment: The live demo may take a while to load, which can be a bit confusing. As can be seen there, in *C++17* the code works as expected. But the same is already the case for **C++11**, see [modified version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WVYAifjXOkvgkSTu)