# Defining a variable that is either an existing value or a new one in C++

Tags: c++

Can I make the code below work **without copying** the object b?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
        public:
                A() = default;
                A(const A& a) { cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
                A(A&& a) { cout << "move ctor\n"; }
                A& operator=(const A& a) { cout << "copy\n"; return *this;}
                A& operator=(A&& a) { cout << "move\n";  return *this;}
};

A Gen() {
        A x;
        return x;
}

int main() {
        bool cached = true;
        const A b;
        const A& a = cached ? b : Gen();
}
```

It seems like when `cached` is true, then the copy ctor is called.

*Edit: in the real code, the class A is kinda big, so I want to avoid copying.
*Edit 2: I made `b` as constant, to clarify the intent.

Comment: I can think of a way to do this so that only a move constructor gets called when `cached` is false.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How?

Comment: Would that answer your question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, the problematic part is when `cached` becomes true so that `b` gets copied.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aznY5dhTW

Comment: or https://godbolt.org/z/4b34zEh8a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overall type of your conditional operator is *not* a reference type, because the 'false' branch is not a reference. Thus, even in the 'true' branch, the `b` object has to be copied, in order to match the type of the `Gen()` call. The assignment makes a reference to that copied object.

In your case, you can avoid this copy operation by a simple cast of the object returned by `Gen()` in the 'false' branch, to a reference to that object:

```cpp
const A& a = cached ? b : static_cast<const A&>(Gen());
```

Note that this cast is being performed (implicitly) in your original code, by the assignment operator (which, if `cached` is `false` will create a reference to the returned object).

Answer (score 4):

When using the ternary operator, `b` is handled as *glvalue*. That will cause a copy constructor call. If you want to avoid that, write `std::move(b)` which provides you with *rvalue* reference. In that case move constructor will be called.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688464/why-and-when-does-the-ternary-operator-return-an-lvalue).

Comment: But that would change the value `b`, doesn't it?

Comment: @wk_j: `std::move` is just a cast, so no modification by itself.

Comment: @Jarod42 I mean, eventually a move constructor is called, so that the object `b` changes. Oh, on second thought, I should have posted the question with `b` as const.

Comment: @wk_j: Avoid to modify your question in a way which invalidate existing answer. Here, with the move, you got `const A&&` from `std::move(b)`, and `A` from `Gen()`, common type should be `const A`, so copy would be done.